# How to add a datagrid using django?

Tags: python, django, datagrid

I'm trying to learn django since I'm newbie in it.
One task that I'm about to do is adding a custom datagrid into a webpage.
The things that datagrid needs to have are:

- connection to a model
- The queries to the database (edit, delete, add)
- A search box

First of all I need to know how to add a datagrid. Is there any django-lib except dojango that could be suitable for me?
I have already read dojango lib.
I'm using django version 1.8
Any helper is welcome to share the knowledge.

Thanks and appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the [Django Admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/) is perfect for your needs.

Comment: I have read the webpage you already mentioned. The thing i need is doing the whole in one page while django-Admin does not do it. for example I want to delete a record? I must click on the pk and then delete it.could you please let me know how to add delete button in the page itself?

Comment: What do you mean? You want to delete records on the list page?

Comment: Yes sir. I need to have it in the list_filter page however it's possible

Comment: That function is already built in. You check the checkboxes for the item you want to delete, then you pick delete in the drop down menu

Comment: You are right. That's why I don't know how to add the other queries in this dropdown menu. For example edit action

Comment: Delete item is default. Show us your code by asking a new question.